# instance error in sonar-eclipse configuration

Tags: eclipse, ant, sonarqube

Hi,
Am using sonar in eclipse using ant.when I try 'associate with sonar', unable to get any page to select for the project. So I went to

> 'preferences-->sonar-->server'

n gave the sonar url as:

> http:// localhost:9000
>
> username:admin
>
> password:admin

but it is showing as error **instance**
so what instance should be given to sonar?

Comment: Can you open localhost:9000 in your browser and see Sonar?

Answer (score 1):

You must first run a Sonar analysis on your project and be able to see the results in your browser, before you can actually associate your project in Eclipse.